# CODEIGNITER dependent dropdown is not showing selected value when update

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, hmvc

I'm a beginner in javascript. I have a dependent dropdown, my problem is that in dependent dropdown when someone is editing, while editing the dropdown is not automatically selected. Here is my form code:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="prov_id">Provinsi
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <?php
                        $additional_dd_code = 'id="reg_province" class="select2_single form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" tabindex="-1"';
                        echo form_dropdown('prov_id', $prov_options, $prov_id, $additional_dd_code);
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="city_id">Kota/Kabupaten
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <select name="city_id" id="reg_city" class="select2_single form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" tabindex="-1" >
                            <option value=""></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#reg_province').change(function () {
            var prov_id = $('#reg_province').val();
            if (prov_id != '') {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?= base_url() ?>reg_city/fetch_city",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {prov_id: prov_id},
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#reg_city').html(data);
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })
```

And this is my controller for updating the dependent dropdown:

```
function fetch_city() {
    $prov_id = $this->input->post('prov_id', TRUE);
    if ($prov_id == TRUE) {
        $query = $this->get_where_custom_order_by('prov_id', $prov_id, 'city_name');
        foreach ($query->result() as $item) {
            echo '<option value="'.$item->city_id.'">'.$item->city_name.'</option>>';
        }
    }
}
```

In the dependent dropdown, the only problem I have is when it comes to an edit. It should have shown the selected id. But in fact, it shows no data. So, how should my code be?

Comment: try calling `$('#reg_province').trigger('change')` in the edit form

Comment: Where should I put the code in? Does it replace $('#reg_province').change(function () {}? If so, how to implement?

Comment: add it in `$(document).ready(function () {...` after `$('#reg_province').change(function () {...` ends

Comment: It works. Thank you very much, it helps me a lot. But, I have next problem: How to make the option selected?

Comment: ok. let me solve that too

Answer (score 0):

Do this for default value

```
// in this handler
success: function (data) {
   $('#reg_city').html(data);

   // add below line
   if(city_id){
     $('#reg_city').val(city_id);
   }
}
```

Comment: where should I put that in?

Comment: just after `.change()`, and `city_id` will be the id for city to be selected by default

Comment: I don't get it, sorry. Can you show me how it should be?

Comment: Yep, it's clear enough. But I'm sorry, it doesn't work

Comment: Hello mate @thphobe9312

Comment: Yes . Issue persists?

Comment: Check your  mail.